# Webservices in Delphi XE4

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have to create and consume a webservice in Delphi XE4. I am totally new it and never used webservices in Delphi before. Can anyone help me with some basic tutorials?

Comment: It is not right place for looking of tutorials i guess, just try to search "Delphi web service" in google or any other search engine, you will like it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good starter tutorial from Pawel Glowacki:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2008/12/18/38624

It is written for Delphi 2009, but i think it is still worth looking at.